# How to set Default opening window in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have an application that has two different login windows for two different types of users of application, say one is *client* and the other is *administrator* , now i want to have an option on both the `Login` windows to set the default opening window, something like a `checkbox` having label as *set this is as your default Login window* ..

How can i achieve this??

May i use a `.properties` file to set the default window? (and How?)

Or, a `Main.java` class which loads first and decides the default GUI window to load first??

I preferred the 2nd way...but your views are welcomed, also please provide some example codes to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a JCheckbox on both login windows. When the user logs in succesfully, look up the value of the checkboxes, set a preference using:

```
private static enum LoginWindow {
    CLIENT, ADMIN;
}
...
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this);
if (client.getSetAsDefaultCheckbox().getValue())
    prefs.put("PREF_WIND",LoginWindow.CLIENT.name());
else if (admin.getSetAsDefaultCheckbox().getValue())
    prefs.put("PREF_WIND",LoginWindow.ADMIN.name());
```

When you load your application:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this);
String prefWindow = prefs.get("PREF_WIND",null);
if (prefWindow!=null) {
    LoginWindow loginWindow = LoginWindow.valueOf(prefWindow);
    switch(loginWindow) {
    case ADMIN:
         // switch to admin
         break;
    case CLIENT:
         // switch to client
         break;
    }
} else
    // Default
```

Comment: Great! Sounds good...will try and come back if anything good or bad happens.. :)

Comment: method userNodeForPackage in class java.util.prefs.Preferences cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<?>
  found: com.tcs.booth.gui.frames.Main
  reason: actual argument com.tcs.booth.gui.frames.Main cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<?> by method invocation conversion

Comment: I got this error with `Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this);` line compilation.. M writing the code in a method in `Main.java` class.

Comment: Ok. problem solved, using `getClass()` in place of `this`, now code is working thanks...ans is accepted... :)